# Index a collection in Mongodb having array of objects for fast update query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document which looks like this:

```
{ name:"xx",
  surname:"yy",
  job_history:[{company:"aa",salary:"bb",experience:"cc",ip_address:"xx.xx.xx.xx"},{company:"aa",salary:"bb",experience:"cc",ip_address:"xx.xx.xx.xx"}]
}
```

The size of collection is 13.5GB and i need to perform update on ip_address. I have all the ip_address in excel sheet original and replacement values. I tried to index the job_history.ip_address but the following index is not used for the update query some how. The update is taking long time to perform single update(around 2 minutes). I have tried bulk_write() and it is taking time as well. Any suggestion how to perform an efficient update on such collection or how to index for efficient update.
To give more information on dataset. There are 1.5 million documents in the collection. The structure of each document is exactly the same as above. The  job_history array has either 1 or 2 objects of the exactly same structure.
My question is How can i speedy up this update ? Indexing which fields will actually speedy up the update ?

Comment: how many documents in total is available in the collection. And, what is the max 'job_history' length. Would be better if you could share few more documents.

Comment: @Abishek I have updated the question with the details.

Comment: While running update query use `$hint` operator to force the query optimizer to use a specific index

Comment: Why are you assuming the index is "not being used"? did you check this or did you just not see performance increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13.5GB is not a big collection for mongoDB could be some storage issue , few questions maybe of help as well as:

1. How many replicaSet members you have and are they near by or deployed in different geographical areas?
2. What writeConcern you use for the update query?
3. How much RAM & CPU your member has , do the indexes fit in memory?
4. Is the database under heavy utilisation ( how many reads/writes per second ) ?
5. What is the mongodb version and storage engine?

Check this steps:

1. mongoimport your csv/xls to a new  temporary collection "ipchange" with following document schema:

   ```
   { _id:1, ipold:"x" ,ipnew:"y"}
   ```

   example mpngoimport command:

   ```
    mongoimport -d <yourDB> -c ipchange --type csv --file ipchange.csv --headerline
   ```

   example ipchange.csv file:

   ```
     ipold,ipnew
     19.16.1.2,192.168.1.2
     1.2.3.4,192.168.1.3
   ```
2. Create index for your targeted collection on "job_history.ip_address" field:

   ```
   db.createIndex({"job_history.ip_address" :1 })
   ```
3. Execute the following query:

   ```
    db.ipchange.find({}).forEach(function(doc){ 
    db.collection.update({
    "job_history.ip_address": doc.ipold
    },
    {
     $set: {
      "job_history.$[x].ip_address": doc.ipnew
     }
     },
     {
     arrayFilters: [
        {
         "x.ip_address": doc.ipold
         }
       ],
        multi: true,
        writeConcern: 0,
        wtimeout: 30000,    // 30sec max
        j: false
      })

    })
   ```

Please, note writeConcern:0 & journaling: false  here set for speed  , but if you need write confirmation you can change to "majority" afcourse sacrifice the speed ...

4. When you are sure operation was executed successfully you can drop the temporary collection with:

   ```
    db.ipchange.drop()
   ```

Explained:

1. You load the xls/csv file to temporary collection.
2. Create index so the old IPs to be identified faster.
3. Execute forEach on the ipchange collection and update your targeted collection with the necessary changes , please, note the multi:true will update all documents where the old IP is found with the new IP from the list.

One more thing: You can confirm if the index is used via explain:

```
     db.collection.explain("executionStats").update(...)
```

In the output you will see something like:

```
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN"
```

instead of:

```
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN"
```

[update query playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i5YundnOnKz)

Summary:
Afcourse you can add some paralelisation with  bulk_write/ordered:false in some multi-threading script and split input data in ranges  per bulk , but the important task here is to use the index in your update query part so you speed up the individual queries.

Comment: To answer the questions : 1. All the datasets are on my Local machine
2. I did create the index as you have mentioned and there was no performance difference
3. It is 16gb Ram and i checked its being used like 95-98%
4. I think yes.Not sure how to check that
5. Mongo DB version 4.4.12

Comment: The point 3 and 4 I have not tried. Will give it a try and let you know with the result. Thank you for such a descriptive answer. I hope it works for me

Comment: 4. mongotop , mongostat , top , sar -d